# I don't have iframe ID or XPath, and I want to type data into textbox under the iframe

Tags: xpath, iframe, css-selectors, cypress

I have one website and I am testing payment workflow. How to interact with elements under the iframe.
Please check the HTML code of my website.[image]

Iframe src link changed every 30 minutes so I can not use it as a selector.
Please let me know any better idea.

Comment: Are there multiple iFrames on the page? If so, is this one always the `nth` iFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) node package.
2. In your cypress/support/commands.js file, add the following:

```js
import 'cypress-iframe';
```

3. Then in your test write:

```js
cy.iframe('iframe[src*="uat.freedompay.com"]')
  .find('#CardNumber')
  .type('4444333322221111')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure about this since you don't share the page URL or entire HTML.
As I see here you can try locating the iframe by XPath, something like this:

```
//iframe[contains(@src,'hpc.uat.freedompay.com/apy/v1.5/controls')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, here is how I solved it:

```
cy.get('.__PrivateStripeElement > iframe') // selector of the iframe
      .then(function ($foo) {
      const $iFramebody = $foo.contents().find('body')
  
      cy.wrap($iFramebody)
        .find(".CardNumberField-input-wrapper input") // selector of the field
        .type('4242424242424242122912355101');      // typing the value          
      });
```

You can use cypress inspector tool to locate the best unique selector of the iframe.
More info can be found in the article by one of the founder of cypress: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/